# control an ASP.Net treeview in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

How can I write Javascript to expand and collapse a particular parent of a `TreeView` when i click on the parent node?

If one of the parent nodes is expanded, then if I click on that it should collapse; and if already collapsed, then vice versa.

Comment: What js framework are you using? Post more details in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li>
        <span class="title">Title</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="title">Item 1</span></li>
            <li><span class="title">Item 2</span></li>
            <li><span class="title">Another item</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span class="title">another one</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tree span.title').click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

When using jQuery.

[Here is an example](http://harmen.no-ip.org/so/test2.html)

Comment: jQuery is actually a Javascript library, which makes Javascript a little easier to write: http://jquery.com/

Comment: can u pls provide in javascript because im totally new in javascript as well treeview